# Keycodes not working in Mozilla with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code in javascript which get keycodes of different keys and set it to hidden field.
Hidden field is then manipulated by server side code. My code is:

```
function TriggeredKey(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var keycode;
   if (window.event){
     keycode = event.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
   }
   alert(keycode);
    document.getElementById("<%=hdfkey.ClientID %>").value = keycode;
   _dopostback();
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome but not in Mozilla. Can someone please provide me the solution for this problem?

Comment: Here is the detailed answer related to it. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43470694/6733426)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function TriggeredKey(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var keycode;
   if (window.event){
       //this check fails in mozilla/
       //so the variable keycode is undefined
       keycode = event.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
   }
   if(!keycode){keycode = e.which}
   //solves the issue
   alert(keycode);
   document.getElementById("<%=hdfkey.ClientID %>").value = keycode;
  _dopostback();
}
```

### Fiddle

[Check the fiddle in mozilla](http://jsfiddle.net/v9n65/4/)

### Fiddle result

[image: Fiddle result]

Comment: Thanks for the rply but again same problem is there.

Comment: I currently run Firefox 10.0.2

Comment: yes, I have used this code on keydown event of a textbox in asp.net. In fiddle it is shown on keypress. same prblm in keydown event

Comment: what is this problem? Can you be a bit more specific? What do you get in the alert?

Comment: ok, but what exactly is the problem? Is the alert showing properly but the element not being updated?

Comment: In chrome i get the keycode of that key but in mozilla it always show undefined for whatever key is pressed. i want that keycode in the hiddenfield to manipulate it at server side code but because of undefined keycode its not working at all in mozilla

Comment: update the code you've posted here with the changes you've made

Comment: function TriggeredKey(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var keycode;

        if (window.event) {
            keycode = event.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
        }
        if (!keycode) { keycode = e.which }
        alert(keycode);
 _dopostback();
}

Comment: This code is working in fiddle but when i m implementing this in my code its not working

Comment: well I meant you to update the question, but no matter. The code you posted also works for me. I'm sorry, but I can't figure out any issues