# JavaScript keycodes are not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I am using JavaScript keycodes, they are not working in Firefox but working in Chrome and IE. I have debugged the code in front end for Firefox I am getting keycode as `0`.

This is my code:

```
$scope.Validate = function(event,indexVal){
    if ((event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91)|| (event.keyCode > 159 && event.keyCode < 166) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || (event.keyCode == 165) ||(event.keyCode == 32)
                        || (event.keyCode == 164) || (event.keyCode == 130) || (event.keyCode == 181) || (event.keyCode == 144) || (event.keyCode == 214) ||
                        (event.keyCode == 224) ||(event.keyCode == 233)) {
                }else{
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
}
```

Can you please suggest a way to achieve this functionality in Firefox too.

Comment: `var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode`

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please give some more clarification please

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is working in both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.keyCode not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555687/event-keycode-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, `event.keyCode` does not always work, depending on the binding event. You'll have to use `event.which`. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555687/event-keycode-not-working-in-firefox/43470694#43470694) for more info.

```
$scope.Validate = function(event,indexVal) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if ((key > 64 && key < 91) || 
    (key > 159 && key < 166) || 
    (key > 96 && key < 123) || 
    (key == 165) ||
    (key == 32) ||
    (key == 37) ||
    (key == 39) ||
    (key == 164) || 
    (key == 130) || 
    (key == 181) || 
    (key == 144) || 
    (key == 214) ||
    (key == 224) ||
    (key == 233)
  ) {
    // Do something.
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: working fine but how can I allow left and right arrow in mozilla

Comment: Arrow keys have the keycode from 37 to 40 (left, up, right, down) respectively. So you'll have to add them into your conditions.

Comment: in chrome it is accepting by default. but even if I keep 37 it is not allowing arrow.

Comment: it is working like http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-a-uppercase-ascii-code-65.html

Comment: ASCII is not keycode! Keycodes are number representations of the keys on your keyboard, whereas ASCII is the number representation of a particular character.

Comment: can you please give me some example for writing ascii code of left and right arrow

Comment: It's not ASCII code you need... Anyway, add two conditions to check for 37 and 39 in the if clause. Updated my answer for it

Answer (score 0):

It's working but slightly different

```
$scope.Validate = function (event, indexVal) {
    var code = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (!(
            (code > 64 && code < 91)
            || (code > 159 && code < 166) 
            || (code > 96 && code < 123) 
            || ~[165, 32, 164, 130, 181, 144, 214, 224, 233].indexOf(code)
    )) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

> **Deprecated** `KeyboardEvent.keyCode`
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Comment: nice let me try once

Comment: $scope.Validate = function(event,indexVal){} do I need to pass this event and indexVal to this function

Comment: `event` will be enough; but, possibly for other validation purposes `indexVal` will be used as well

Comment: Just FYI: `KeyboardEvent.which` is also marked at MDN as [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)

Comment: @Murali, it won't have some differences at all... but I've updated the answer. As I've mentioned, if `indexVal` is not in use, just remove it from scope