# restricted special character script works on chrome but not in firefox.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here, I want to restrict some special character except ( ) ? / - , and alphanumeric characters.Below code properly works on chrome but not in Firefox.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function ValidAlphabet(e,t) {

            if (window.event) {
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            }

            else { return true; }
            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (event.keyCode >= 48) && (event.keyCode <= 57) || (charCode == 32) || (charCode == 63) || (charCode >= 40 && charCode <= 41) || (charCode == 44) || (charCode == 45) || (charCode == 47))
            {

                return true;
            }
            else {

                return false;
            }

    };
</script>
```

**code design**

```
<body style="background-color: Cornsilk">
   <form id="form1" class="body" runat="server" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return ValidAlphabet(event,this)" onpaste="return false">
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.keyCode not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555687/event-keycode-not-working-in-firefox)